# Can you call signal() from within a signal handler?

Tags: unix, signals, sigchld

I have a supervisor program that generally wants to receive `SIGCHLD` events.  However, after it receives `SIGTERM` or similar signal, it would be safe and desirable to ignore `SIGCHLD` events to prevent zombies.  The issue is that I'm not sure if it's legal to call `signal(2)` when already inside a signal handler, so that e.g. `SIGTERM` calls `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)`.  It doesn't *appear* to cause problems, but I know there are many restrictions placed on what you can do in a signal handler, and I'm unable to figure out whether calling `signal` is in the forbidden zone.

So: is this legal, reliably?  If not, is there an alternative way to make sure that no children still running at the time of the `SIGTERM` can possibly zombie, even if they aren't properly `wait`ed on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Linux, look at the manpage for [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). There is a list of async-signal-safe functions. It says:

> POSIX.1-2004 (also known as POSIX.1-2001 Technical Corrigendum 2) requires an implementation to guarantee that the following functions can be safely called inside a signal handler:

`signal()` is in the list. So it's safe.